# What is the OAuth package used by ASP .NET in the "Internet Application" template in ASP .NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net

What is the OAuth package used by ASP .NET in the "Internet Application" template in ASP .NET MVC 4?

I searched OAuth in the NuGet package manager and there was a lot of OAuth libraries/packages, which is the default one which is officialy used in the said template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package used in MVC4 should be `DotNetOpenAuth 4.3.4.13329` in the newest version, not including PreRelease versions. to get the version, which is used on your machine in your specific MVC4 template, open up the properties of the installed DotNetOpenAuth package and note the version number. You should be able to install the xcact version of this with:

```
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth -Version <version>
```

On http://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth/4.3.4.13329 you'll see all dependencies, which will be installed alongside, if you issue the command `Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth`

If you just need the core of OAuth you are probably looking for

```
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core
```